# Receiving a sms from a specific number

Tags: c++, arduino, gsm

I am working on a project where my Arduino ATMEGA328 interfaced in SIM900 GSM Shield will receive an sms from the specific number.

I was able to receive the message. But I want my GSM to only receive from a specific number. For example, i only want to receive from +639123456789 number only. Numbers like +639111112222 and +639998887777 and other will be discarded. Can anyone can help me?

EDIT: This is my code.

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
    #include <string.h>

    char inchar; // Will hold the incoming character from the GSM shield
    String s = "";
    SoftwareSerial SIM900(2, 3);
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);

      // wake up the GSM shield
      SIM900power(); 
      SIM900.begin(9600);
      delay(20000);  // give time to log on to network.
      SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");  // set SMS mode to text
      delay(100);
      SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r"); 
      // blurt out contents of new SMS upon receipt to the GSM shield's serial out
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("Ready...");
    }

    void SIM900power()
    // software equivalent of pressing the GSM shield "power" button
    {
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      delay(7000);
    }

    void loop() 
    {

    if(SIM900.available() > 0)
{
if(SIM900.find("+639123456789 ") && SIM900.find("AUTO"))
{

Serial.println("AUTOMATIC asd");
SIM900.println("AT+CMGD=1,4");
}
}
    }
```

Comment: First receive it, then check the number, and do nothing if it doesn´t match? Discarding before you received it won´t work.

Comment: @deviantfan I was looking for the correct syntax format. I tried SoftwareSerial.find("+639123456789") but it does not work. Do you have other way of detecting the senders number?

Comment: deviantfan is right, this is nothing to do with GSM.  Post a small bit of C++ code that tries to filter out the number, and people can point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: @SList I have put on my code. Feel free to edit. :))

Comment: You just can't stop the telephone network from sending the SMS to you. It's a Short Message Service, one packet. At the network level there's no "offer-accept-deliver" exchange, that would be too complex. For that kind of service, use TCP instead of SMS.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I am receiving texts from other numbers, what I do is after I received it, It immediately deletes the message once it does not satisfies the condition. Now, my problem is how can I perform command when I received an SMS from my specific number. For example to light up an LED. Can you please cite some example.

Comment: @Vonne: Your question is unclear.  That comment sounds like you're struggling with `IF this THEN that` logic. But you already have written an `if` statement in the code, and probably thousands in your life. What's the specific problem with this one?

Comment: Have you done basic debugging, i.e. step through and watch variable values, or log values after every line, to find out what your code is actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to receive the message. But I want my GSM to only receive
>   from a specific number.

Do you wish to stop the GSM from receiving SMS from unknown numbers, or do you want to output to serial when the conditions are met?

If it's the former, you may want to talk to your network provider, and consider the architectures pitfalls in this approach.

> It immediately deletes the message once it does not satisfies the
>   condition

On that same if condition where you discard the sms if not sent from numXXX, 
add an

```
else{
SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r");
Serial.println("AUTOMATIC asd");
SIM900.println("AT+CMGD=1,4");
// or write high to led pin if that's what you want.......
}
```

Of course, it would help if we could see that sketch...